# converting list of list to a string gives "none" values

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a **scraper** and I'm creating a list of list and want to store in the text file as a string in every iteration of the outer loop like I've

```
all_products_ids = ['1','2','3']
outer_pro_list = []
product_data = ['data1','data2']
for pro_id in all_products_ids:
    inner_product_list = []
    for prod_data in product_data:
        inner_product_list.append(str(prod_data))
        print("Apending")
        outer_pro_list.append(inner_product_list)
        with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
             f.write(str(outer_pro_list.append(inner_product_list)))
```

what I'm looking in the output is list of list like below without removing "["  "]" in the text file

[[data1,data2],[data1,data2]]

`

Comment: Tell us what you're getting, and what you want.  Your title mentioned "none" values, but your example data doesn't show them.

Comment: `f.write(str(outer_pro_list.append(inner_product_list)))` You're writing the result of the append function, but that function doesn't return anything, so you're writing None.

Comment: `outer_pro_list.append(inner_product_list)` returns `None` which you are then writing to your file. What did you want to write to your file instead?

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ not scrapper.

Comment: Where is `outer_pro_list` defined?

Comment: Can't you just do`[product_data for _ in all_products_ids]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts  I want output in the text file as [ [data1,data2], [data1,data2] ]

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I'm looking for this output in the text file [ [data1,data2], [data1,data2] ]  and I'm getting NoneNoneNone as `str(outer_pro_list.append(inner_product_list))` returning none

Comment: Read all of our comments again, slowly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing what you think you are writing, because list.append does not return a value.

A simplified version of the issue, for illustration.

```
data = []
print ("This is what you are writing:")
for n in range(6):
    print (data.append(n))
    
print ("This is the data you didn't print:")
print (data)
```